# How do I make it that a vector in an array doesn't change its values?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I insert a vector in an array and change the value of the vector, it also changes in the array. How can I safe data in an array in type of a vector without it changing the value when I change the value of the vector?

```
const array10 = [];
let vector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
array10.push(vector);
vector.x = 10;
console.log(array10[1]);
```

Output: (10,0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a copy of the vector in the array. A new vector3 with the same x, y, and z values can be created with [`clone()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.clone):

```js
array10.push(vector.clone());
```